# OpenCMS 10 open graph metas

Tags: jsp, jstl, opencms

I'm trying to print Open Graph meta in main template but I can't get the information about the content shown on the detail page, I'm only able to access the detail container page.

For example, to establish og:image i created a property on theme's .config, but I can't get this information from the "detailed" content:

```
<meta name="og:image" content="<cms:property name="mytheme.ogImage" file="uri" default="" />">
<meta name="og:image" content="<cms:property name="mytheme.ogImage" file="search" default="" />">
<meta name="og:image" content="<cms:property name="mytheme.ogImage" file="element.uri" default="" />">
<meta name="og:image" content="<cms:property name="mytheme.ogImage" file="search.element.uri" default="" />">
<meta name="og:image" content="<cms:property name="mytheme.ogImage" file="/.content/blogentries/be_00009.xml" default="" />">
```

The last is the only one which works, but I neither know how to get the path to the content inside main template.

I suppose there is a simpler way to do it but I don't find it.

Thank you in advance.

PS: I'm working with OpenCMS 10.5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying lots of things, the only "solution" I came with is retrieving the resource from the database making a connection directly in Java as show in [this example](http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Using_OpenCms%27s_Database_connection_pool#Example_jsp).

With this connection I made a SQL query to find the resource related to the javax.servlet.forward.request_uri of the current page.
Once I have the resource (including its file name) I can get its properties with `<cms:property name="mytheme.ogImage" file="${filename}" default="" />`